# combination problem24

Tags: combinatorics

How many 4-digit positive integers are there, where each digit is positive, and no two adjacent digits are same?

ans 9*9*9*9 why this answer is wrong 
we are calculating 4 digit positive number , we can take first value from 1 to 9 ,second 0 to 9 but as we filled first so we can take second value 9 and same as for third

Answer (score 3):

The second digit cannot be $0$, because the problem explicitly specifies that every digit must be *positive*.

So there are only $8$ possibilities for the second digit, and similarly for the third and fourth.

Comment: for example 2045 , this is not a positive number

Comment: How many 4-digit positive integers are there in which all 4 digits are even?  there we have same problem , there why we are including 0

Comment: @user153963: 0 is even but not positive. So if you require _even_ digits, then 0 is a possibility, but if you require _positive_ digits, then it isn't.

Comment: 2045 is a positive number, but it does not satisfy the "each digit is positive" condition.